# MODX фильтры на tagManager2

Tags: php, modx

Делал фильтры по этой статье https://bayguzin.ru/main/uroki/uroki-modx-revolution/tag-manager2.html, товары выводятся, но без дополнительных полей, а фильтры вообще не выводятся.
Если в снипgете завардампить $tm_filters->getFiltersOutput(), то там ничего не выводится.
С чем может быть связанно? Где искать ошибку

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если кому понадобится. Проблема оказалась в настройках mysql в опции only_full_group_by. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23921117/disable-only-full-group-by